# How to add a site collection tempalte to the central administration?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, central-administration, site-template

I am trying to create a site collection template and put it in the "custom" tab in the central administration. In this way whenever i want to create a new site collection i will be able to choose my template. Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following link  to add site collection template:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=218

http://nikpatel.net/2013/01/17/step-by-step-provisioning-new-site-collection-based-on-custom-site-template-in-sharepoint-online-2010/

Comment: I tried this but it is not working the right way. When you do the steps written int the links above, yes you create a site collection from a custom template but only once. If i go to the central administraion with the intention to create a new site collection with the same custom template it is not there it is not int the custom tab. I wand to add a template in the custom tab and it to stay there. In this way i will be able to create site collection with this template whenever i want without uploading a templates every time.

Comment: I dont think so this is possible using site templates. But you can use your custom site definition which will always stay there and you don't need to uplaod it every time.

Comment: I just tried it yesterday and it doesn't stay in the custom tab

Comment: Have you tried using custom site definition? how did you create that custom site definition from your site template?

Comment: I just saved my site as a template and then uploaded the way it is shown in the article above.